# supporting markjs plugin for older browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, highlight

hi i need function included it in this plugin markjs here is demo for it:

https://markjs.io/configurator.html

there is function called wrapMatchesAcrossElements in this plugin which highlight words in different nodes or words between br tags i need only this function to work in old browsers can some one help how to support this function it would be nice if some one support the whole plugin for old browser ,the plugin currently support ie 9 and up

this the function that i want :

```
 key: "wrapMatchesAcrossElements",
            value: function wrapMatchesAcrossElements(regex, ignoreGroups, filterCb, eachCb, endCb) {
                var _this6 = this;
                var matchIdx = ignoreGroups === 0 ? 0 : ignoreGroups + 1;
                this.getTextNodes(function (dict) {

                   var match = void 0;
                        //while ((match = regex.exec(dict.value)) !== null && match[matchIdx] !== "") {
                        while ((match = XRegExp.exec(dict.value, regex)) !== null && match[matchIdx] !== "") {

                        var start = match.index;
                        if (matchIdx !== 0) {
                            for (var i = 1; i < matchIdx; i++) {
                                start += match[i].length;
                            }
                        }
                        var end = start + match[matchIdx].length;

                        _this6.wrapRangeInMappedTextNode(dict, start, end, function (node) {
                            return filterCb(match[matchIdx], node);
                        }, function (node, lastIndex) {
                            regex.lastIndex = lastIndex;
                            //alert(regex);
                            eachCb(node);
                        });
                    }
                    endCb();
                });
            }
```

Comment: What browsers do you need?

Comment: internet explorer 7 would be nice

Comment: for all: https://www.freelancer.com/projects/Javascript/improve-javascript-code-support-old/

Comment: yes this is my project :) i hired  a programmer and i will release this version for every one if the programmer managed to support it

Comment: Great! Would be totally great if it would be available on GitHub too, as a fork

Comment: i see but i'm not sure about license type of markjs but if the original owner of script allowed me i will provide it to the community

Answer (score 0):

While jQuery might run without major issues in older browser versions, we do not actively test jQuery in them and generally do not fix bugs that may appear in them.

Similarly, jQuery does not fix bugs in pre-release versions of browsers, such as beta or dev releases. If you find a bug with jQuery in a pre-release of a browser, you should report the bug to the browser vendor.

[Click here for Source:](https://jquery.com/browser-support/)